# On existence of a convergent subsequence

Tags: convergence-divergence

Let $(a_{(m,n)})_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a double sequence of positive numbers.

Suppose that we know that there exists a limit $\lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{(m,n)}=L$.
Does there always exists an increasing function $m: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{(m(n),n)}=L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean strictly increasing. Then the answer is no:

Take $a_{(m, n)} = 1$ if $m < n$, and $\ldots = 2$ if $m \geq n$. Then $L = 1$. Suppose $m : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is strictly increasing; then $m(n) \geq n$, so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{(m(n), n)} = 2$.

Comment: In your example $(a_{(m,n)})_{m,n \in N}$ are not positive numbers.

Comment: You are correct. You can take under "zero" an arbitrary positive number which differs from 1.

Comment: Alright; corrected.